# how to remove specific char from array in python

Tags: python

```
img = cv2.imread('img/dream.jpg')
(b,g,r)=cv2.split(img)
color = ('b','g','r')
b = cv2.calcHist([img],[0],None,[256],[0, 256])
g = cv2.calcHist([img],[1],None,[256],[0, 256])
r = cv2.calcHist([img],[2],None,[256],[0, 256])
     
for i, col in enumerate(color):
    histr = cv2.calcHist([img],[i],None,[256],[0, 256])
    plt.plot(histr, color = col)
    plt.xlim([0, 256])   
    
with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    writer.writerow('BGR')
    for row in rows:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

I am trying to read in a picture and show its RGB counts of each pixel.
It's all cool until I tried to write my data into a csv file.
Here is what it look like:

```
B,G,R
[0.],[0.],[631788.]
[0.],[0.],[418355.]
[0.],[0.],[105815.]
```

All I need is to remove the '[' and ']' from my array.

I am new to python I am not sure whether the array is tuple dictionary or something else.

I have tried the replace() method however it appear an error message
'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'replace'

Comment: To discover the type of the object, you can use the type(obj).

Comment: Where did you specify rows?

Comment: Please update your question with a small amount of text of the csv file, rather than a link to an image.

Comment: You could try writer.writerow(row[0])

Comment: @quamrana do you mean to post my csv file?

Comment: Not all of it. Just enough lines to get a representative idea, say 3 lines.

Comment: Just use the `edit` link and replace the link to the image with the text of the csv file.

Comment: the system said i haven't been agreed to post a image lol
it seems like i haven't post enough article

Comment: Doh!, Now someone else is editing your question. I was going to replace your image link with some sample file contents.....

Comment: i apologize for not knowing how SO is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every value in your array is within its own list. In python you access elements of a list using an index.

In your case, you can convert your array of lists (with each list having only one value `i[0]`) using the following:

```
delisted_array = np.array([i[0] for i in your_array_of_lists])
```

This list comprehension says: "take the value from first index of each (list) found in this array and put those values in a list".

Eg.

```
In [70]: a = np.array([[1],[2]])

In [71]: a
Out[71]: 
array([[1],
       [2]])

In [72]: delisted_array = np.array([i[0] for i in a])

In [73]: delisted_array
Out[73]: array([1, 2])
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need is to convert a `list` to `String` by

```
list_string = ''.join(list_name)
```

as well if you have a `matrix`

you will need

```
for item in list_outer:
  item = ''.join(item)

list_outer = ''.join(list_outer)
```

Comment: i have converted it to list but still appears error
could you explain it more clearly thanks for your reply

Comment: you mean convert it to string , what error you have ?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/0Yhcx91
this is what happen when i convert it to string and do the same implement as i did above

Comment: could you update the code with where exactly you convert the list to string , and which one

Comment: @Paga, i have update the answer , if you have a matrix

Comment: i tried to do what you teach me but it appears a error message
"equence item 0: expected str instance, numpy.ndarray found"
so i use {strg = ''.join(str(e) for e in g)} to convert it
and here is the code i changed
https://imgur.com/a/3eb0ed7

Comment: @Paga, that's not what i wrote !

Comment: but it appears error so i try another way to convert it however it's still error :(

Comment: what is  error , ididn't provide any `numpy` lib, please take a look in the answer you commenting